# Convert String to ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have string like `"User.first"` is there any way to convert that string to ActiveRecord query:

```
User.first
```

This string can be anything and I want to make it executable.

Comment: The obvious but evil solution is to use `eval`, but this opens up a whole world of security issues. Especially since it seems like this is user input—is it?

Comment: so the question is, is it always "model.classmethod"? and where this string comes from? reliable source? and why looks as Ruby code and not a data structure of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [kernel#eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) documentation:

> eval(string [, binding [, filename [,lineno]]]) → obj click to toggle
>   source
>
> Evaluates the Ruby expression(s) in string. If binding is given, which
>   must be a Binding object, the evaluation is performed in its context.
>   If the optional filename and lineno parameters are present, they will
>   be used when reporting syntax errors.

However, as @andrew-marshall correctly points out, this is a huge security hole if you are using any sort of unvalidated input. See [Locking Ruby in the Safe](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html) as a starting point for more information about tainted data and $SAFE levels.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with sth like

```
Kernel.const_get("User").send('first')
```

Comment: This would still require parsing the string first, so it doesn't really address the OP's question.